# Convert pixel(x, y) for loop to numpy.nditer Iterator

Tags: performance, numpy, image-processing, iterator, pygame

I'm trying to speed up some pygame image processing code, which iterates over every pixel and modifies them. I'm looking at the numpy nditer function, but I'm struggling to work out how to implement it.

```
    # Iterate though main image
    for x, row in enumerate(main):
        for y, pix1 in enumerate(row):

            # Check the pixel isn't too dark to worry about
            if pix1[0] + pix1[1] + pix1[2] > 10:

                # Calculate distance to light source
                light_distance = np.hypot( x - light_source_pos[0], y - light_source_pos[1] )

                # Calculate light intensity
                light_intensity = (300 - light_distance) / 300

                # Apply light color and intensity to the specular map, apply specular gain then add to main
                main[x][y] += light_color * light_intensity * specular[x][y] * specular_gain

                # Apply light color and intensity to the diffuse map, apply diffuse gain then add to main
                main[x][y] += light_color * light_intensity * diffuse[x][y] * diffuse_gain
```

I'm iterating over an arrays of the image data [x][y][r][g][b], as generated by `pygame.surfarray.pixels3d()`. The array is not a copy, its a reference to the actual memory contents.

How would I create an iterator that walks through the x and y coords, and applies the changes, as fast as possible?

From what I can work out, it would be faster to operate on the pixels in memory order, and keep everything inside the iterator loop?

EDIT: The snippet above is for easier digestion, but the entire script is gisted [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/aa31b085aae7a0382fe8). To run it, you'll need some source images to work with.

Comment: Could you list out the shapes of the inputs involved?

Comment: @Divakar It varies depending on the image size, but we can assume for now its a 300x200 image. That means main, diffuse and specular are arrays like this array[0:299] => array[0:199] => array[0:2]. I'm walking across first, and then second array (x and then y), then operating on the final array of pixel colors,

Comment: `nditer` does not speed up iteration. The Python version is useful if you plan on later using it In Cython code.  It's not going to help here.

Comment: Use `[x,y]` style indexing.

Comment: @hpaulj I thought that it removed the python function calling overhead between iteration calls? Or am I confused, and it really needs Cython to make a difference?

Comment: So, if I assume main : `(M,N,3)`, light_source_pos : `(2,)`, light_color, specular_gain, diffuse_gain as three separate scalars, specular : `(M,N)`, diffuse : `(M,N)`, would that be correct, where M and N are shape parameters?

Comment: `nditer` still requires the Python iteration call: `for i in np.nditer(x):`  v `for i in x:`  In fact it adds a layer.  It was developed primarily to consolidate iteration alternatives within the compiled code.

Comment: I can find only 2 uses of `nditer` in `numpy` `.py` files,  One is the convenience `np.ndindex` function.  Another is several function call layers down in `np.save`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code, it seems the implementation is surely parallelizable and as such we could have a vectorized implementation. Now, in the quest of removing loops, we need to extend dimensions of the inputs at certain places, which would bring in [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) into play.

For the sake of easier code lookup and maintenance, I am assuming these abbreviations -

```
S = specular
D = diffuse
LSP = light_source_pos
LC = light_color
S_gain = specular_gain
D_gain = diffuse_gain
```

Here's one way of vectorizing the problem -

```
# Vectorize light_distance calculations and thereafter for light_intensity
LD = (np.hypot(np.arange(M)[:,None] - LSP[0], np.arange(N) - LSP[1]))
LI = (300 - LD) / 300

# Vectorized "LC * light_intensity * S[x][y] * S_gain" and 
# "LC * light_intensity * D[x][y] * D_gain" calculations
add_part = (LC*LI[...,None]*S*S_gain) + (LC*LI[...,None]*D*D_gain)

# Get masked places set by "pix1[0] + pix1[1] + pix1[2] > 10", which would be 
# "main.sum(2) > 10". Use mask to add selective elements from add_part into main 
main += (add_part*(main.sum(2)[...,None] > 10))
```

---

**Runtime tests and verify outputs**

Define functions -

```
def original_app(main,S,D,LSP,LC,S_gain,D_gain):
    for x, row in enumerate(main):
        for y, pix1 in enumerate(row):
            if pix1[0] + pix1[1] + pix1[2] > 10:
                light_distance = np.hypot( x - LSP[0], y - LSP[1] )
                light_intensity = (300 - light_distance) / 300
                main[x][y] += LC * light_intensity * S[x][y] * S_gain
                main[x][y] += LC * light_intensity * D[x][y] * D_gain


def vectorized_app(main,S,D,LSP,LC,S_gain,D_gain):
    LD = (np.hypot(np.arange(M)[:,None] - LSP[0], np.arange(N) - LSP[1]))
    LI = (300 - LD) / 300
    add_part = (LC*LI[...,None]*S*S_gain) + (LC*LI[...,None]*D*D_gain)
    main += (add_part*(main.sum(2)[...,None] > 10))
```

Runtimes -

```
In [38]: # Inputs
    ...: M,N,R = 300,200,3 # Shape as stated in the comments
    ...: main = np.random.rand(M,N,R)*10
    ...: S = np.random.rand(M,N,R)
    ...: D = np.random.rand(M,N,R)
    ...: LSP = [3,10]
    ...: LC = np.array([2,6,3])
    ...: S_gain = 0.45
    ...: D_gain = 0.22
    ...: 
    ...: # Make copies as functions would change those
    ...: mainc1 = main.copy()
    ...: mainc2 = main.copy()
    ...: 

In [39]: original_app(mainc1,S,D,LSP,LC,S_gain,D_gain)

In [40]: vectorized_app(mainc2,S,D,LSP,LC,S_gain,D_gain)

In [41]: np.allclose(mainc1,mainc2) # Verify outputs
Out[41]: True

In [42]: # Make copies again for timing as functions would change those
    ...: mainc1 = main.copy()
    ...: mainc2 = main.copy()
    ...: 

In [43]: %timeit original_app(mainc1,S,D,LSP,LC,S_gain,D_gain)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.28 s per loop

In [44]: %timeit vectorized_app(mainc2,S,D,LSP,LC,S_gain,D_gain)
100 loops, best of 3: 15.4 ms per loop

In [45]: 1280/15.4 # Speedup
Out[45]: 83.11688311688312
```

Comment: I'm just trying to get it to work with my implementation now. Can you tweak your answer so that LC is an array [0:2], and make S and D the same shape as main?

Comment: @Oliver So, you are saying main, S and D are : (M,N,3) shaped; LSP is (2,) shaped; LC is (3,) shaped; S_gain, D_gain are scalars? Check out the edits?

Comment: Fantastic. Works a charm. Many thanks for your help. Do you have any reading recommendation for learning broadcasting as you have done? I started looking at the numpy docs but it was really heavy going and seem to require that I had read and understand the rest of the numpy docs up to that point.

Comment: @Oliver As linked in the post, follow the documentation for broadcasting. Also, personally I like to work without loops as much as possible whether with my MATLAB or NumPy work. So, I would have to answer to it with saying that just keep practicing, look into more such broadcasting and/or [`vectorization`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy+vectorization) based Q&A. Or ask questions on understanding broadcasting here on SO, good luck!